# How do I select an empty element in XPath?

Tags: selenium, xpath

We select elements with Django 1.4 tests and Selenium like this:

```
self.assertEqual(1, len(self.selenium.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href='#'][@class='button save-as'][@title='Save As...'][text()='Save As']")))
```

(The class inherits from `LiveServerTestCase`).

The problem is that sometimes there are elements without text, and if we select with `[text()='']` it fails (the len is 0). How can I select elements without text?

**Update**: Because `[text()='']` didn't work, I had to assert two lines to assert no text:

```
self.assertEqual(1, len(self.selenium.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href='#'][@class='button properties'][@title='Properties']")))
self.assertEqual("", self.selenium.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='#'][@class='button properties'][@title='Properties']").text)
```

Now I can assert the same with one line:

```
self.assertEqual(1, len(self.selenium.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href='#'][@class='button properties'][@title='Properties'][not(text())]")))
```

Comment: Surely the fact there is *sometimes* text there and *sometimes* there isn't is actually an application bug or is this some weird feature of Django?

Comment: No, there is always no text in this element. The 'Save As' text is another element.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use XPath's  `not()` function.

```
//a[@href='#'][@class='button save-as'][@title='Save As...'][not(text())]
```

Comment: It works, just one fix - it's `[not(text())]` and not `[text()='Save As' or not(text())]` - there is only one option of no text.

Comment: Ah, so you know before hand that the elements should be empty? I read your question as you weren't sure what the element contained. Edited.

Comment: Yes, some elements contain text and some are empty. They are different elements.

Comment: By the way, do you know why `[not(text())]` works and `[text()='']` doesn't?

Comment: I'm not sure, I pulled this out of some of my old code. I think it has something to do with an empty node (no children) and a text node containing an empty string (children) being treated differently in XPath.