# WebDriver find by xpath where //input[@value='empty']

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to find an input element with an 'empty' value by xpath.

Something like `//input[@value='empty']`. I don't mean the word 'empty', but the value is empty or blank.

What Xpath will return such element?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779467/how-do-i-select-an-empty-element-in-xpath) it provides an option for defining an empty xpath.

Comment: Can you update your html code and the things that you tried in the question so that people can help you out?

Answer (score 1):

Since the link I posted in the comment is a potential solution
So, I thought to post it as an answer:

[How do I select an empty element in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779467/how-do-i-select-an-empty-element-in-xpath)

Edit:
Based on advice from the comment to duplicate the essential parts of the linked answer (incase the link becomes obsolete), please find it below:

> You could use XPath's  not() function.

```
   a[@href='#'][@class='button save-as'][@title='SaveAs...'][not(text())]
```

Comment: thanks for the nudge @JeffC and ramarajT, I've edited the answer to include the 'solution' from the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

Next time post html snippet so that people will understand parent and target element

the below code will work, but if more input fields with null values are there then more than one result will be returned. [i am sure below xpath will return many results]

so please include parent node in below xpath

```
//input['not(text())']
```

the input belongs to text area, submit button, radio button , check box ....

again, post the HTML snippet next time. when you ask question related to xpath.

Comment: how the `not(text()` is specifically referring to the `value` attribute?