# Python Selenium - finding elements which contain any text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to process all elements which have text. I know I can iterate over the list and process only those which contain text:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
my_elelements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*")
for elm in my_elements:
    if elm.text!=""
    'processing of text
```

but is there a quicker way only find elements with text, with selenium's `driver.find_elements_by_` without finding all elements and then filtering only those with text...? Is there a wildcard that can be used here ?

Comment: You could use XPath's  not() function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779467/how-do-i-select-an-empty-element-in-xpath/23779762

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `only those with no text`? Can you show us how you do that?

Comment: I clarified the question. I want to filter out those events which have no text, and only process those which have some text - any text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following x-paths to get all elements with text.

1. `//*[text()]`  -- it will returns all element with text including parent nodes
2. `//*[text()][count(*)=0]` -- it returns all element with text only child nodes

or you can use the following x-path to get the all elements without text.

1. `//*[not(text())]`  -- it will returns all element without text including parent nodes
2. `//*[not(text())][count(*)=0]` -- it returns all element without text only child nodes

Comment: The XPath `//*[text()]` is going to return some elements with no text (those with just a line break), the elements with text but hidden, and all the text within a `<script>` or `<style>`. You could improve it by formatting the white spaces and by starting after the body with `html/body//*[text()[normalize-space()]]`.