# Check if XML document is empty (that the root has no child nodes) using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a XML document. In this case, it is empty:

```
<Converting/>
```

I want to throw an exception if the XML document is empty, and I am using XSLT-1.0. I imagine something like

```
<xsl:template match="root[not(*)]"/>
```

However, this does not seem to work out for me. Any ideas?

Kind regards

edit: I want to create this inside a template, so I cannot use a template

Comment: [How do I select an empty element in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23779762/205233) suggests `root[not(text())]` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a template what match the root element and then within this template count child node. If count is 0, write a text into output or throw an exception.

### Approach 1

```xslt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:if test="count(./*) = 0">
            <xsl:text>doc is empty</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Approach 2

```xslt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:if test="count(./*) = 0">
            <xsl:message terminate="yes">doc is empty</xsl:message>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Pavel, thanks a lot for the response. I need to create this inside a template. I get an error that templates cannot have child templates. Any ideas?

Comment: Try this way:
`<xsl:if test="count(/*/*) = 0">
   <xsl:message terminate="yes">doc is empty</xsl:message>
</xsl:if>`